# total of all rows in new column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sum, rowsum

question:- get the total of all one two columns

```
              bar                 baz                 foo              
          one       two       one       two       one    two        
name
A       0.895717  0.805244  1.206412  2.565646  1.431256   1.431256     
B       0.410835  0.813850  0.132003  0.827317  0.076467   0.076467     
C       1.413681  1.607920  1.024180  0.569605  0.875906   0.875906
```

output:-

```
               bar                 baz                 foo   
          one       two       one       two        one      two     
name                                                                 total of one   total of two
A       0.895717  0.805244  1.206412  2.565646   1.431256  1.431256   sum of one    sum of two 
B       0.410835  0.813850  0.132003  0.827317   0.076467  0.076467   sum of one    sum of two
C       1.413681  1.607920  1.024180  0.569605   0.875906  0.875906   sum of one    sum of two
Total    sum        sum      sum       sum         sum      sum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate per secon dlevel of MultiIndex in columns and then add first level `all` for `MultiIndex`, so possible use left join by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = pd.concat({'all': df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).sum().add_prefix('total_')}, axis=1)
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
        bar                 baz                 foo                 all  \
        one       two       one       two       one       two total_one   
A  0.895717  0.805244  1.206412  2.565646  1.431256  1.431256  3.533385   
B  0.410835  0.813850  0.132003  0.827317  0.076467  0.076467  0.619305   
C  1.413681  1.607920  1.024180  0.569605  0.875906  0.875906  3.313767   

             
  total_two  
A  4.802146  
B  1.717634  
C  3.053431
```